# Poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29). when Xdebug trying connect to PhpStorm from docker container

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying debug CLI script, and Xdebug can't connect to PhpStorm.
I see error `Operation now in progress (29).` in Xdebug remote log.
I'm sure Xdebug configured right, but I don't know how to debug PhpStorm.

Summary from phpinfo() generated by https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

```
Tailored Installation Instructions
Summary
Xdebug installed: 2.6.1
Server API: Command Line Interface
Windows: no
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 7.1.24
Zend API nr: 320160303
PHP API nr: 20160303
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: no
OPcache Loaded: no
Configuration File Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Configuration File: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Extensions directory: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
You're already running the latest Xdebug version
```

Xdebug log

```
Log opened at 2019-02-19 11:59:37
I: Connecting to configured address/port: 46.201.50.194:9000.
W: Creating socket for '46.201.50.194:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2019-02-19 11:59:37
```

Xdebug config

```
xdebug

xdebug support => enabled
Version => 2.6.1
IDE Key => PHPSTORM

Supported protocols
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.cli_color => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_includes => On => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0 => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off => Off
xdebug.collect_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On => On
xdebug.default_enable => On => On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.POST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value => no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value => no value
xdebug.dump_globals => On => On
xdebug.dump_once => On => On
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value => no value
xdebug.filename_format => no value => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0 => 0
xdebug.gc_stats_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.gc_stats_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name => gcstats.%p => gcstats.%p
xdebug.halt_level => 0 => 0
xdebug.idekey => PHPSTORM => PHPSTORM
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256 => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1 => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => 2 => 2
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_addr_header => no value => no value
xdebug.remote_autostart => On => On
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600 => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => 127.0.0.1 => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /app/xdebug.log => no value
xdebug.remote_mode => req => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9000 => 9000
xdebug.remote_timeout => 200 => 200
xdebug.scream => Off => Off
xdebug.show_error_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value => no value
xdebug.trace_format => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_options => 0 => 0
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c => trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128 => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 512 => 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3 => 3
```

[image]

Comment: 1) Check what comment PhpStorm is using to run that script in a debug mode. It looks like the IP address might be wrong/not detected correctly. 2) I would suggest to always (on Linux/Mac) use custom port for Xdebug (e.g. 9001) instead of default 9000. Less possible conflicts with possible php-fpm etc. 3) Ensure that IDE is listening on required port (and not some another process)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the reply. What do you mean, check what comment PhpStorm is using? How I can check the comment?

Comment: Sorry .. it meant to be a "command" there. When you click "Debug" for a CLI script, it will show you the exact comment that is executed. I think you will see the remote_host param there. usually it would be 127.0.0.1 .. but in your case it might be more specific IP

Comment: FWIW with a certain configuration I get the `Operation now in progress` warning but then the client connects fine, so I'm not sure it's related to the actual error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Xdebug can't connect to PhpStorm because PhpStorm was not reachable by my external host ip.
How I debug it.
First I checked from docker container that PhpStorm listen port (9000 in my case)

```
nc -vz external_ip 9000
```

It got `(tcp) failed: Connection refused`
I try the same from the host and also got the error
Then I tried from host

```
nc -vz localhost 9000
```

And I got `[tcp/*] succeeded!`
So the problem in xdebug.remote_host not in PhpStorm probably

I found host ip in container

```
netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}'
```

Put it in xdebug.remote_host and now it works correctly

Thanks for @LazyOne

Comment: Works like a charm: Centos 7 / Php 7.2.20 / xdebug 2.7.2

Comment: Which network driver are you using? I'm using `bridge` and when I use the IP from the result of that netstat command I get this output `(UNKNOWN) [127.17.0.1] 9000 (?) : Connection refused`

Comment: `netstat -nr | grep '^0\.0\.0\.0' | awk '{print $2}' ` this command helped me to find out the IP of the vagrant machine and then added the same in `remote_host` in ini and it worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 16):

In my case I simply set the following xdebug conf:

```
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

`host.docker.internal` should 'magically' find the host's IP (cf. [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)). Note that this requires Docker v18.03+ and currently only works on Mac and Windows hosts.

Comment: No dice for me; Docker desktop 2.3.0.3, Engine 19.03.8. From host `nc -vz localhost 9000` -> `[tcp/*] succeeded!`. From container `nc -vz host.docker.internal 9000` -> `host.docker.internal [192.168.65.2] 9000 ? open`

Comment: This was the solution for getting step debugging working with Sail on wsl2 for me.

Comment: This only works when the IDE and docker host are on the same machine.

Answer (score 2):

May be your xdebug.remote_port 9000 is using by php-fpm. You try changing other port. Example xdebug.remote_port=9001 and in launch.json file still port=9000

Answer (score 1):

If someone doesn't want to hardcode or modify their docker, Dockerfile, or compose file (maybe someone is using a 2.x xdebug, it doesn't support environment variable). Adding the header **X-Forwarded-For** by using a header modifying extension on the browser so as to set **$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']** is a very convenient approach. Don't forget the configuration **xdebug.remote_connect_back=1**.

Dockerfile

```
FROM  php:7.1-apache

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

ModHeader extension
[image: Xdebug helper]

xdebug.log

```
Log opened at 2021-07-06 16:06:59
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.17.0.1:9000.
W: Creating socket for '172.17.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
E: Could not connect to client. :-(
Log closed at 2021-07-06 16:06:59

Log opened at 2021-07-06 16:07:40
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.30.112.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix to this error was simply clicking the phone icon in PhpStorm twice to disable and then re-enable listening for debug connections.

It shouldn't change anything but it worked because before that I fixed a bunch of other issues, one of them being that port 9003 was blocked by something else. Apparently PhpStorm doesn't warn when it can't use the specified port, so after resolving other issues it might be necessary to re-initiate listening for debug connections.

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the mapping from phpstorm in PHP->Server, you have to map the project file to the absolute path of the server eg. src -> "/var/www/html/test/src"

Also the xdebug file from the server that contains the ip address

Answer (score -1):

I have opened "Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security" (Windows firewall settings) and have found that I have two rules, which appeared not clear from where, that block the phpStorm.

I disabled them - and the xDebugger started working for me.

[image: Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security]