# Why does the debugger not work in PhpStorm remote web server?

Tags: debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I installed Xdebug on the hosting. Using phpinfo (), I made sure that it was enabled. I set it up step by step in PhpStorm. Validation without errors

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the window with my server settings

[image]

I installed the Xdebug helper extension in Google Chrome. I turn on the wiretap, put breakpoints in the code, update the page in the browser, but nothing happens. Please help =(

PhpStorm Version 2020.3, Xdebug Version 3

P.S. Here is the information about Xdebug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUmEh.png)

Comment: I haven't worked with remote servers in PhpStorm but step-debugging itself requires the server to start a network connection with your PC. That normally implies knowing your IP address, redirecting ports in router and opening firewall. Have you done these arrangements? Also, set a file with `xdebug.log` so you can find out what's happening.

Comment: And on top of what @ÁlvaroGonzález says, you can also use the new xdebug_info() function to see what Xdebug is really trying to do, in case making a log file is not a simple task. That function's output also will give you links to documentation, which is what the log file can't do.

Comment: @Derick thank you, xdebug_info () gave me more information. But I do not know what to do with this error. I tried ports 9000, 9001, 9003, I changed the host from an IP to a domain

Comment: Xdebug is trying to connect to your IDE. You need to use the same port as what you've configured there (either 9000, or 9003, would be most likely). However, the *IP* address you fill in there, needs to be the IP address of the machine where your IDE runs, with all the requirements for being contactable from the open internet, as @ÁlvaroGonzález wrote.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thank you for paying attention to my problem. The log file is empty after several attempts.

Comment: @Ann13 If Xdebug log is empty: **1)** Make sure it's writeable (enough permissions) **2)** Check the path (esp if a tmp folder is used) -- some systems now have "virtualized" temp that is unique for each process? See the Xdebug docs -- it has a mention of that: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#log (at the end of the section for that option) **3)** Xdebug does not see "debug me" flag (the Xdebug cookie that the browser extension sends etc). Try either telling Xdebug to try to debug every single script (regardless of the flag) or try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code.

Comment: @Ann13 **4)** Some Linux config/tool can also prevent Xdebug from making outgoing connections (e.g. SELinux). **Anyway**, you better post results of your `xdebug_info()` output -- will show your actual live config.

Comment: @Ann13 And BTW -- the Remote Host IP -- it as to be the IP of your machine where IDE is running as seen from that server. It has to be able to connect from outside to your IDE (as it's Xdebug that connects to IDE and NOT other way around). The firewall on your PC/router most likely will be blocking such connections. If so -- look into SSH tunnels: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html

Comment: @LazyOne  Thank you for your advice. After changing the log entry rights, it started working. I posted a screenshot in the question xdebug_info (). Thanks to you, I realized that xdebug is accessing my IDE and specified the IP address of my machine, but there is still no connection

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54766718/poll-success-but-error-operation-now-in-progress-29-when-xdebug-trying-conn for some additional checks. Have you configured your router?

Comment: Well ... 1) your very first screenshot shows `9000` port, while actual live settings have `9003`. 2) Firewall / router issue? Are you sure your router/whatever allows incoming connections on that port and they are forwarded to the right PC in your LAN? 3) make sure that PhpStorm is listening for incoming debug connections on that port: the phone handle is green (or Debug panel is already displayed) and use `netstat` to confirm that.

Comment: Use google and search for `portforward checker` to ensure that the port is opened/allow in your router and desktop firewall (be it router firewall, Windows one or your Antivirus/Internet Security software). Otherwise (if it's too much) -- look into SSH tunelling (the link was already provided in my 3rd comment)

Comment: Double check the IP address -- maybe also enable `discover_client_host` option and see what IP Xdebug will detect. P.S. https://portforward.com/ for how-tos.

Comment: @LazyOne I read on the Internet that port 9003 is suitable for the xdebug 3 version and tried to use it. I disabled the firewall. netstat responded with "TCP 0.0.0.0:9003 WEB:0 LISTENING". Google has confirmed that port 9003 is open.

Comment: @LazyOne Enabled the "discover_client_host" option and returned [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: bla.bla.bla.220:9003 (from REMOTE_ADDR HTTP header), bla.bla.bla.220:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Comment: You can use `telnet` or alike tool and connect from your remote server to your local -- try that 9003 port and see the response. If it connects then connection is good; if no connection -- either wrong IP:port; or firewall/router (even outgoing firewall on your server/hosting)... or no app is listening here on a local PC. P.S. when using netstat -- ensure that it's PhpStorm that listens on that port and not some another app (but then, on PhpStorm can detect already in use port Windows ... it's on Mac where it has issues with that).